# Why does my render look so horrible?

Tags: rendering, artifacts

If have pretty much no idea about blender but for some reason my render looks absolutely horrible! [image: the render]

The preview and even the image while rendering looks just fine.[image: the preview]

The white noise in the preview is, of course, also not meant to be there.

Edit: the effect gets worst with more samples. Link to the .blend file: [The file](https://emilemilchen.de/87)

Comment: Could you share a .blend file?(https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: Looks like a GPU error or outdated

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Emir. My view looks fine.

Comment: I already tried updating the Nvidia drivers and blender. But i have sucessfully worked with blender just a few days ago. I also created the project today.

Comment: I now not just updated but reinstalled my GPU drivers wihich seems to have solved the problem.